# Auto adjusting size for two iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Basically when I use one iframe, it works great, here's the code:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframed" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
    
    
<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");
// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

I can't seem to do an auto adjust for two iframes.

I have tried this:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframed" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframednr2" scrolling="no"></iframe> 

<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");
// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

This applies auto adjust to the first iframe only.

I have also tried adding two scripts for both iframes:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframed" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
<iframe id="iframe2" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframednr2" scrolling="no"></iframe> 

<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");
// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>

<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe2");
// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

The above applies only for iframe2, but don't apply for iframe1

Have no idea what's going on here.

Maybe I'm missing something?

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first fix, it is because you set 2 elements with the ID `iframe1` and HTML doesn’t allow that.

In the second fix, you didn’t use 2 variables, but only `iframe`, and because of that, it was written over. To fix that, try using 2 separate variables. (eg `iframe1` and `iframe2`)

Here is it with 2 different variables:

```html
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframed" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
<iframe id="iframe2" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/iframednr2" scrolling="no"></iframe> 

<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");
// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe1.onload = function(){
    iframe1.style.height = iframe1.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>

<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe2 = document.getElementById("iframe2");
// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe2.onload = function(){
    iframe2.style.height = iframe2.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```